# Are file locations stored in PostreSQL catalog?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to learn a bit of PostgreSQL, and I am currently trying to understand the catalog. I think that if it stores all the metadata of the DB, should it also store things like the file locations?

I mean, I can (not involving the catalog) do:

```
SHOW data_directory;
```

or

```
SHOW config_file;
```

etc etc. I think it would be quite interesting to retrieve the same information via a catalog query, but I am not finding information about it. At most, I could do:

```
SELECT pg_settings.name, pg_settings.sourcefile FROM pg_settings WHERE pg_settings.sourcefile LIKE '%.conf%';
```

and kind of see where the files should be stored. I wondered if there is a more direct way to get that information.

Maybe is not possible?

Comment: `SELECT current_setting('data_directory');`

Comment: Thanks! It looks a bit silly that I was trying to do my long `pg_settings.name` query, and it was just that easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config file and data directory location cannot be stored in the system catalogs, because the database cannot read the system catalogs until it knows where they are.

It's a bit like putting the map to your buried treasure into your treasure chest.

(Note that `pg_settings` is not technically a system catalog. It is a *view* that shows GUCs as configured by `postgresql.conf` / `ALTER SYSTEM ... SET`, by `ALTER USER ... SET`, by `ALTER DATABASE ... SET`, etc.)

Comment: Great example! It was helpful to help me finishing understanding